# mouse move event on listview of a dialog box in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created a dialogbox. On which I have created two list views.
I have created a sub class for list view.
I wanted to know where is mouse, I mean on which list view.
After that I will find the index of list view using CListCtrl::HitTest().

Now I am getting the index using HitTest but Mouse move is common for both List view.
So how I can distinguish the list view in mouse move event.

Finally I am going to create the tooltip according to list view and index of that list view.

Answer (score 0):

[CListCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78%28VS.80%29.aspx) inherits form CWnd. You can get the mouse pointers coordinates implementing [CWnd::OnMouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3158baat%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You mainly have two options:

- either subclass the CListCtrl and implement OnMouseMove as you want in the derived class
- either implement OnMouseMove in the parent window (dialog window) and test the coordinates of the mouse against the coordinates of the two list controls.

Whatever solution you pick keep in mind that OnMouseMove is called very often and the implementation of the function must be very light otherwise it will load the computers resources and the application will lag.

HTH,
JP.

Answer (score 0):

If all you really want is to display a tool-tip whenever the mouse hovers over some control you have, there's no need getting your hands so dirty with hit-tests, mouse coordinates, etc. Just use windows' built-in mechanism for that.

Assuming that your dialog class is the parent of the two list views:

- From the dialog's `OnCreate()` call `EnableToolTips()`.
- Add a handler to the message map, such as: `ON_NOTIFY_EX(TTN_NEEDTEXT, 0, OnTtnNeedText)`.
- Implement `OnTtnNeedText()` in the dialog class. Example:

  ```
  BOOL CMyDialog::OnTtnNeedText(UINT id, NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
  {    
      TOOLTIPTEXT *pTTT = (TOOLTIPTEXT *)pNMHDR;  
      pTTT->hinst = AfxGetResourceHandle();  
      switch ( pNMHDR->idFrom )  
      {
          case IDC_LV_LEFT:
              pTTT->lpszText = "I'm lefty!";
              break;
          case IDC_LV_RIGHT:
              pTTT->lpszText = "I'm righty!";
              break;
      }
      return TRUE;
  }
  ```

And that's more or less it. Refer to this for more information: [article](http://weseetips.com/2008/04/28/how-to-enable-tooltip-for-your-dialog-controls/)

Comment: pNMHDR->idFrom is actually a HWND, you have to use ::GetDlgCtrlID to get your control ID.